# How to inherit another class's attributes in python

Tags: python, class

I have two classes: Info and Connection. Connection is supposed to inherit Info. My end goal is to have Connection be able to access Info's attributes, so that for every instance created of Connection, an instance of Info will be passed in. And then Connection will have access to this instance of Info's attributes.

I've been going through forums and tutorials, I understand the concept but everything I've tried doesn't seem to get this working. I've tried using `super()` and then just calling Info's `__init__` inside Connection's `__init__` function to no avail.

As a test, with the code below, I've tried accessing the attribute `slot_number` through an instance of the Connection class (i.e. `Connection.slot_number`) but it didn't work. I get the error `Info has no attribute 'slot_number'` even though Info clearly has an attribute called `slot_number`. Can anyone give me some clarification on how to do this?

```
class Info(object):
    def __init__(self, slot_number, board_type, board_part_num, prod_part_num):
        self.slot_number = slot_number
        self.board_type = board_type
        self.board_part_num = board_part_num
        self.prod_part_num = prod_part_num

class Connection(Info):
    def __init__(self, system, sn, phase, ip, port):
        super(Info, self).__init__()
        self.system = system
        self.sn = sn
        self.slot_number = slot_number
        self.phase = phase
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
class Person():
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

  def getName(self):
    return self.name
  def getAge(self):
    return self.age


class Student(Person):
  def __init__(self, name, age, id):
    self.id = id
    super().__init__(name, age)

  def getId(self):
    return self.id

new_student = Student('Student', 20, 666)

print(new_student.getName())
```

As for your specific case:

```
class Info(object):
    def __init__(self, slot_number, board_type, board_part_num, prod_part_num):
        self.slot_number = slot_number
        self.board_type = board_type
        self.board_part_num = board_part_num
        self.prod_part_num = prod_part_num

     def getSlotNumber():
          return self.slot_number

class Connection(Info):
    def __init__(self, system, sn, phase, ip, port, slot_number, board_type, board_part_num, prod_part_num):
        super().__init__(slot_number, board_type, board_part_num, prod_part_num)
        self.system = system
        self.sn = sn
        self.slot_number = slot_number
        self.phase = phase
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
```

And you could access Info's properties by creating get methods.

```
new_connection = Connection('system', 'phase', 'ip', 'port', 'slot_number', 'board_type', 'board_part_num', 'prod_part_num')
new_connection.getSlotNumber()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `super().__init__`, you need to pass the values that are expected. You either need to hard code them

```
class Info(object):
    def __init__(self, slot_number, board_type, board_part_num, prod_part_num):
        self.slot_number = slot_number
        self.board_type = board_type
        self.board_part_num = board_part_num
        self.prod_part_num = prod_part_num

class Connection(Info):
    def __init__(self, system, sn, phase, ip, port):
        super().__init__(0, "foo", 3, 9)
        self.system = system
        self.sn = sn
        self.phase = phase
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

c = Connection(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)
```

or pass them to `Connection.__init__` so that they can be passed on.

```
class Info(object):
    def __init__(self, slot_number, board_type, board_part_num, prod_part_num, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.slot_number = slot_number
        self.board_type = board_type
        self.board_part_num = board_part_num
        self.prod_part_num = prod_part_num

class Connection(Info):
    def __init__(self, system, sn, phase, ip, port, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*kwargs)
        self.system = system
        self.sn = sn
        self.phase = phase
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

c = Connection(system=arg1,
               sn=arg2,
               phase=arg3,
               ip=arg4,
               port=arg5,
               slot_number=arg6,
               board_type=arg7,
               board_part_num=arg8,
               prod_part_num=arg9)
```

The second approach is preferable, because the purpose of `super` is to support multiple inheritance, and in that case, you don't necessarily *know* which class's `__init__` method is going to be invoked by `super`. The best thing you can do is accept arbitrary keyword arguments, use the arguments you *do* know about, and pass the rest on. This includes `Info`, even if you are *statically* inheriting from `object`, because you don't know when defining `Info` what the method resolution order (MRO) of `self` is going to be at run time.

Comment: Okay thanks that was very helpful. The whole reason why I created the two different classes above was so that I wouldn't need to pass so many variables to the ```Connection``` class each time it is instantiated. Is there anyway I could just pass the instance of ```Info``` itself to ```Connection``` instead of the excess variables?